# Migration:rollback and reset in production environment

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I am just learning the basics of Laravel and learned about migrations. I think that this functionality is pretty cool, but I was wondering about the safety of migrations.

According to laracasts, when you create a migration that creates a new table, the rollback of that function is dropping the table. It makes sense but isn't this very unsafe? It could possibly lead to loss of data by running a single command.

Is this still best practice? Can and should you protect your production environment against this kind of destructive commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `php artisan migrate:reset` in production it asks you to confirm it.

I understand what you mean though as you can run `php artisan migrate:reset --force` to skip confirmation.

If you believe this should be changed in Laravel, why not raise it as an issue on Laravel's GitHub page and spark up a discussion with Laravel's creator? https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues